# OpenCv API to extract I-frames

Tags: keyframe, opencv, python

Does `opencv-python` have API to extract I-frames from a video?

I am using `ffprobe` to extract `I-frames` from video and passing frame numbers to `opencv` for manipulating frames but this requires iterate video frames in two steps; one for detecting `I-frames` and one for manipulating those.
so I searched for a direct way to extract `I-frames` from video using just `opencv` but **nothing found**.

If there is a solution, I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: opencv is too high-level to do this. But you can use ffmpeg programmatically by using the libav functions in your code, to extract/read frames and decode them if you like to. OR you could change the openCV functions (it is open source!) or adapt a MyVideoCapture class (based on the open source VideoCapture class) to return additional frame information to the user.